# what do I need to make this flutter installation work

Tags: flutter, installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVcTr.jpg)

it's my first time to try software related stuff.

Could you help me on this issue.

I have no idea what's happening while I'm trying to install the flutter in my mac.

I did restart the whole process and it happens again.

Do i need something else to make this installation work?

Thank you

I did restart the whole process and it happens again.

Comment: You need to install Xcode from the Apple App Store first.

Comment: I see.   I install that immediately.   Thank you

Comment: Hi Bryce, Thanks for the sharing.  After I install the Xcode, seems like git is required.  Could you guide me to install the git?   Thank you

Comment: Try to follow this tutorial: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos